# Text color changed without code to do so

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I had an action link like so in visual studio 2013

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.PlayerName, "Details", new { id = item.PlayerID })
```

I then changed it  to this to add some color (using bootstrap 3)

```
<span class="text-primary">@Html.ActionLink(item.PlayerName, "Details", new { id = item.PlayerID })</span>
```

Everything was fine until I decided to change the color but it didn't work it remained the same which I thought was weird. I have now even changed the code back to it's original state without the span tag and it's still colored. How is this even possible. I have cleared my browser cache, tried another browser and even restarted my machine.

**EDIT: This is all the code for that page**

```
@model IEnumerable<Ping_Pong.Models.Player>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p class="spacetop">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Player", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerScore)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerDiv)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerActive)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.PlayerName, "Details", new { id = item.PlayerID })
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="label label-success">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerScore)</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="label label-success">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerDiv)</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerActive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PlayerID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-sm" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PlayerID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" })
        </td>
    </tr>

}

</table>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML that is generated for your span and anchor element? Also, in the bootstrap CSS file, can you show all the styling that mentions `text-primary`? That will help people who are trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: That's what i'm saying there is now no span tag anymore I already removed it and it's still happening as for the css file it is just bootstrap css unmodified. However here it is from the source page <a href="/Player/Details/3">Your Name</a>

Comment: Inspect the element on the generated page and check for the CSS styles applied.

Comment: To find out where the colour is coming from, use the browser developer tools to look at the styling of the `<a>` element. If you inspect an element, the dev tools can tell you where the styling for that element comes from in the css file.

Comment: Found out the reason now. Just posted the answer. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found out why it was only staying blue.

I was using a span tag around an ActionLink which doesn't work.

**The correct way is to add a new class inside the ActionLink like so**

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.PlayerName, "Details", new { id = item.PlayerID }, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```